monaco-kusto how to consider all lines as one query context, even empty lines
I have integrated the monaco editor with the monaco-kusto language plugin inside my web application.
Through the editor, when editing a query, the editor isolates the context from other queries in the same file. Doing so, a variable reference is not detected even if it has been declared before because an empty line is separating the two statements. (Here the context is highlighted in white)

Is it possible to force the plugin to consider all lines as one context without having to select all lines manually or without having to remove empty lines for the variable to be detected?

